# org mode: retrieve current heading and parents programmatically

Tags: org-mode

In `org-mode` whenever I have point on heading it shows me in the mini buffer the full hierarchy. For example, if I have the following in a Org file:

```
* lvl1
** lvl2
*** lvl3
    some text
```

And I put point on lvl3 it shows `/lvl1/lvl2/lvl3` in the mini buffer. Is there a specific function I can call to obtain this information? I sometimes need to retrieve context and with this it would be easier, no need to move point to the heading.

Comment: What version of org-mode are you using?

Comment: @Melioratus I forgot to mention that I'am using spacemacs. I'am using the org layer and `org-version` tell me the version is "9.1.13".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`org-get-outline-path` will return a list with the heading hierarchy.

`org-format-outline-path` will take such a path and format it for display. This is what goes into your mini-buffer.

Comment: To test this, add an emacs-lisp code block after "some text" in your sample file with content: (org-get-outline-path t), place cursor after the parenthesis, and press C-x C-e.

Answer (score 0):

`org-display-outline-path` displays (or optionally returns a string of) the hierarchy **already formatted**.

It also has a few optional parameters to customize its behaviour (defaults included in parenthesis):

- include file name? (no)
- current heading? (no)
- custom separator (defaults to "/")
- just return a string rather than display it? (no).

To obtain a formatted string of the heading including the curret one (lvl3):

```cl
(org-display-outline-path nil t "/" t)
```

=> `#( "lvl1/lvl2/lvl3" ...<text properties> )`

To strip the text properties from it -- **just the string**:

```cl
(substring-no-properties (org-display-outline-path nil t "/" t))
```

=> `"lvl1/lvl2/lvl3"`

---

IMO this method is simpler than using org-get-outline-path, append current heading (lvl3) and joining it with string-join.

The function `org-display-outline-path` seems to have been available since *around version 7.9*.

- [git log relating to this function](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/log/?qt=grep&q=org-display-outline-path)
- [Documentation for this function (on Worg)](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-display-outline-path)